# Unable to disable nor shrink recentf-mode

Tags: spacemacs, performance, recentf, exwm

Loading recentf (180MB) makes emacs unusable recently. Simple `M-x` calls take almost a minute each and everytime I see a recentf related message.
As others already asked I'm unable as well to disable `recentf-mode` (it simply continues running after toggling). Deleting/moving the file didn't help.

Any ideas on how to mitigate?

My .xinitrc

```
    emacs --daemon -f exwm-enable
    exec emacsclient -c
```

Unfortunately emacsclient misses the `-Q` option in order to debug

Comment: My current workaround consists of restoring an old (4.0KB) `recentf` file from a backup

Answer (score 2):

There are several variables defined in `recentf.el` that you can use to control what gets saved in the recentf list.  And you can use command `recentf-cleanup` to cull entries that don't satisfy those restrictions.

A few of the variables (user options, in fact) that you can use:

- `recentf-max-saved-items`: Maximum number of items of the recent list that will be saved.
- `recentf-max-menu-items`: Maximum number of items in the recentf menu.
- `recentf-keep`: List of regexps and predicates for filenames kept in the recent list.
- `recentf-exclude`: List of regexps and predicates for filenames excluded from the recent list.
- `recentf-auto-cleanup`: Define when to automatically cleanup the recent list.

Use `M-x customize-option` to customize any of those...